# Spring Integration JDBC execution times statistics

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration in order to connect to an external JDBC database and I want to track execution times per db connection.

Apart from using Spring AOP and wrapping my service method to measure statistics, is there any way to measure times directly in the spring-integration? Meaning to get exactly how much the database connection was used per request?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC is used not only in Spring Integration, so it is not correct to request such a feature exactly from the Spring Integration perspective. Any other applications without any integration features should benefit from such a feature as well.

I think what you are looking for is covered by the DB metrics in Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-jdbc

If you don't use Spring Boot, consider to apply the mentioned HikariCP: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics

Otherwise you always can override `execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)` and wrap a super call into your own metric to measure a time for that `execute()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your help